# How to replace gzip compressed data with other data and still have a valid .gz file?

Tags: compression, gzip, crc

I'm experimenting. I created a .txt file with the word `hi` and run `gzip test.txt` to compress it.
This gives me a file test.txt.gz with the following bytes:

```
1F 8B 08 08  E6 E8 3F 60  00 03 62 2E  74 78 74 00
CB C8 04 00  AC 2A 93 D8  02 00 00 00
```

With the software 101 editor, I found out that the first line is the header.

`CB C8 04 00` are the compressed data

`AC 2A 93 D8` is "CRC of the data section"

`02 00 00 00` is the "size of the uncompressed input"

What I'm trying to do (I don't know if it is even possible): I want to have my own characters as "compressed" data but want the .gz file to be still valid.

I tried replacing `CB C8 04 00` with `62 62 62 62` (letter 'b' 4 times) but the file is invalid then. Then I tried to replace `AC 2A 93 D8`, too with the CRC32 value of "bbbb", but the file is still invalid. I can't decompress it. Running `gzip -d test.txt.gz` returns "unexpected end of file".

Is it possible what I'm trying to do? If yes: what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CB C8 04 00` is a valid deflate stream. `62 62 62 62` is not. A gzip member is a gzip header, a valid deflate stream, and a gzip trailer.

Deflate streams are defined in [RFC 1951](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1951).